# Attempting to make a work-around for requiring fields for Fire Department Pre-Incidence Solution while maintaining Status integrity

Tags: arcade, arcgis-online-webmap

I'm working with a heavily customized version of the Pre-Incidence Solution in which fire fighters can conduct site visits and collect pre-incident data directly into a form on a 'Site Visit' web map in ArcGIS Field Maps.

The building polygons are symbolized by a 'Status' field with options for 'Assigned' 'Needs Attention' or 'Site Visit Completed'.

I'm trying to make sure that the 'Status' will only be updated to 'Site Visit Completed' if certain fields in the Site Visit form are fully completed and haven't been left empty. However, I'm new to coding and I've mostly been learning in Python and JupyterNoteBooks--I don't have much experience with Arcade and have struggled figuring out how to go about this.

Due to the nature of their job, I cannot require fields to be completed using the Required check box on the form. If a crew gets called half way through a site visit, it would be problematic if they had to discard all collected data because of required fields preventing them from submitting what they had collected so far.

I'm assuming it will be based mostly on the IsEmpty function, but how to I utilize it in a way that will resemble IsNotEmpty?

This is my first time asking a question online about coding before, so if there's any way I can provide more clarification please let me know.